# How to join get data from 2 tables and left join into 1 table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have this table

```
tbl_emp

    ID| name |
    1 |  a   |
    2 |  b   |
    3 |  c   |
    4 |  d   |

tbl_remit

    ID|   remit   |
    1 | 2012-01-01|
    2 | 2013-01-01|
    3 | 2012-05-01|


tbl_report

    ID|   report  |
    1 | 2012-01-01|
    2 | 2013-01-01|
    3 | 2012-05-01|
```

I need to join all 3 of them in tbl_emp regardless if there is a data in tbl_remit or tbl_report.

Here is the code that I used but failed.

```
    SELECT tbl_emp*, tbl_remit.remit, tbl_report.report from tbl_emp
left join tbl_emp.ID = tbl_remit.ID LEFT JOIN tbl_emp.ID = tbl_report.ID
```

the table i got was

```
ID | remit | report |
1  |  NULL |  NULL  |
2  |  NULL |  NULL  |
3  |  NULL |  NULL  |
4  |  NULL |  NULL  |
```

the table i need is

```
ID |   remit  |  report  |
1  |2012-01-01|2012-01-01|
2  |2013-01-01|2013-01-01|
3  |2012-05-01|2012-05-01|
4  |   NULL   |   NULL   |
```

Comment: You join Syntax is false. That query is really working? Syntax must be `from <table> join <table2> on <condition> join <table3> on <condition>`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to type the ON condition, I wasn't able to copy or memorize the syntax correctly sir, what I meant was `SELECT tbl_emp*, tbl_remit.remit, tbl_report.report from tbl_emp
left join tbl_emp.ID = tbl_remit.ID ON tbl_emp.PEN = tbl_remit.PEN LEFT JOIN tbl_emp.ID = tbl_report.ID ON tbl_emp.PEN = tbl_report.PEN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by joining your other two tables with inner join. And the join the resulted table with the emp table. For that you can use subquery.

```
select * from tbl_emp x left join (
    select a.id as id, a.remit as remit,b.report as report from 
    tbl_remita,tbl_report b where a.id=b.id) y on x.id = y.id
```

Hope it will help.